# Analytic function and connected region.

Tags: complex-analysis

We have the result.

**Let $G$ be an open connected set in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Then the following statements are equivalent.**

**1. $f(z) = 0$ in $G$ for all $z$ **

**2. There is a point $a \in G$ s.t. $f^n(a) = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.**

**3. $\{z \in G : f(z) = 0\}$ has a limit point in $G$**

Can we say $\mathbb{R}$ is open connected set in $\mathbb{C}$? Why or why not?

If we do not consider $G$ as a open connected region, the result will loss its validity. Please give me a counterexample of a function for which it may happen.

Thank you for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is connected in $\mathbb{C}$. However, $\mathbb{R}$ is not open as a subset of  $\mathbb{C}$. In general, any set in a metric space is open whenever it is a union of discs $D_r(a)=\{x:\,d(x,a)<r\}$. 
Now, if $a\in\mathbb{R}$ there is no $r$ so that the *complex disc* $D_r(a)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

That a function is analytic is a local property on the topology of $\mathbb{C}$. This means that a function $f$ defined on a set $\Omega$ is analytic provided that for any $z\in\Omega$ there exist a disc $D_r(z)\subset\Omega$ such that $f$ is analytic on $D_r(z)$.

In particular, it is natural to assume the domain, $\Omega$, in the definition of analytic function is open.

Comment: If we consider $G$ is not connected, the result will not be valid. I am looking for an example where it happens.

Comment: That is actually what I said. To be more explicit: If $G=U\cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are open non-empty and disjoint, then we may define $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ so that $f=0$ on $U$ and $f=75$ on $V$. In other words, on each connected component of $G$ the function is uniquely defined - but we can not establish uniqueness by looking at only one component.

Comment: O! I get it, so eassy! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. If the set is not connected then you can  take the value of the function to be  0 on one connected component and any other constant in another component.

Comment: It is expected. Thanks. What for the next one.